# Use Airflow to run parametrized jobs on-demand and with a schedule

Tags: celery, airflow

I have a reporting application that uses Celery to process thousands of jobs per day. There is a python module per each report type that encapsulates all job steps. Jobs take customer-specific parameters and typically complete within a few minutes. Currently, jobs are triggered by customers on-demand when they create a new report or request a refresh of an existing one.

Now, I would like to add scheduling, so the jobs run daily, and reports get refreshed automatically. I understand that Airflow shines at task orchestration and scheduling. I also like the idea of expressing my jobs as DAGs and getting the benefit of task retries. I can see how I can use Airflow to run scheduled batch-processing jobs, but I am unsure about my use case.

If I express my jobs as Airflow DAGs, I will still need to run them parametrized for each customer. It means, if the customer creates a new report, I will need to have a way to trigger a DAG with the customer-specific configuration. And with a scheduled execution, I will need to enumerate all customers and create a parametrized (sub-)DAG for each of them. My understanding this should be possible since Airflow supports DAGs created dynamically, however, I am not sure if this is an efficient and correct way to use Airflow.

I wonder if anyway considered using Airflow for a scenario similar to mine.

Answer (score 1):

[Celery workflows](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html) do literally the same, *and* you can create and run them at any point of time. Also, Celery has a pretty good scheduler (I have never seen it failing in 5 years of using Celery) - Celery Beat.

Sure, Airflow can be used to do what you need without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Airflow to create DAGs dynamically, I am not sure if this will work with a scale of 1000 of DAGs though. There are some good examples on astronomer.io on [Dynamically Generating DAGs in Airflow](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/dynamically-generating-dags/).

I have some DAGs and task that are dynamically generated by a yaml configuration with different schedules and configurations. It all works without any issue.

Only thing that might be challenging is the "jobs are triggered by customers on-demand" - I guess you could trigger any DAG with [Airflow's REST API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/rest-api-ref.html), but it's still in a experimental state.